# Prevent DML rollback when custom exception is thrown

Tags: exception

In our org we are calling batches from an external system using salesforce API.
When a batch is failing the external system create a bug and it goes into our standard processes.

A new requirement has made us create multiples batches which are called one atfer another in order to transfert ownership of a lot of records accross differents objects.

Each batch in the chain can tag the custom object WalletTranferRequest__c with an error and the last batch will update the request with an error status. (see code below)

```
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    String idWalletError = '';
    List<WalletTransferRequest__c> listWtrFinalStatus = new List<WalletTransferRequest__c> ([SELECT Id, ErrorOnLead__c, ErrorOnOpportunity__c, ErrorOnContract__c, ErrorOnContact__c, ErrorOnSeizure__c, ErrorOnTask__c, ErrorOnEvent__c, ErrorOnCase__c, ErrorOnAccount__c, TransfertRealDate__c, Status__c FROM WalletTransferRequest__c WHERE Id IN: mapWt.keySet()]);

    for(WalletTransferRequest__c wtr : listWtrFinalStatus){
        wtr.TransfertRealDate__c = date.today();
        if(wtr.ErrorOnLead__c || wtr.ErrorOnOpportunity__c || wtr.ErrorOnContract__c || wtr.ErrorOnContact__c ||   wtr.ErrorOnSeizure__c || wtr.ErrorOnTask__c || wtr.ErrorOnEvent__c || wtr.ErrorOnCase__c || wtr.ErrorOnAccount__c){
            wtr.Status__c = 'Error';
            idWalletError = idWalletError + wtr.Id + '; ';
        }else{
            wtr.Status__c = 'Validated';
        }
    }

    List<Database.SaveResult> updateResults = Database.update(listWtrFinalStatus, false);

    if(idWalletError != ''){
        BatchWalletTransferException bwte = new BatchWalletTransferException('Erreur sur les demandes de transfert suivants: ' + idWalletError);
        throw(bwte);
    }
}
```

As said, we want to update the record with an error, but we need to send an exception to the external system or else it wont create a bug and the error wont be monitored automatically.

The thing is when I throw a custom exception the update of the record is rollback(ed?).

I know that when you throw uncatch exception there is a rollback, but is there a way to avoid that? I tried to put a allOrNone in the DML but it prevent just from firing exception not from rollback if there is one.

Will I be forced to do 2 transactions?

Comment: The past tense would be *rolled back*. That said, you can't have an unhandled exception without said rollback. You should inquire if you can make a callout to those systems in your finish method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for now it is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you have only one option:

#### [Platform Event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_apex.htm)

You can publish a Platform Event (with the behavior set to Publish Immediately).

> Publish Immediately to have the event message published when the publish call executes. Select this option if you want the event message to be published regardless of whether the transaction succeeds. Also choose this option if the publisher and subscribers are independent, and subscribers don't rely on data committed by the publisher. For example, the **immediate publishing behavior is suitable for an event used for logging purposes**. With this option, a subscriber might receive the event message before data is committed by the publisher transaction.

Resources:

- https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.platform_events.htm&type=5
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_apex.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I did not think of platform Event.
I will try this, this should work fine